# Access to Python class instance attributes from main() fails

Tags: python, multithreading, class, attributes, keyword-argument

I'm writing a control program that needs multiple configurable, restartable timers which run in their own thread. Originally I implemented this with custom functions and custom event names for all timers. Because this is a really ugly approach, I'm doing a rewrite with a more OO-like approach. Please consider the minimum example below which does everything I need it to do with one exception for which I've not been able to find a solution: I can't access the required class instance attributes (I hope I'm using the right terminology here).

The failing statement is line 74 and commented out. I suspect a problem with the way I pass arguments and kwargs but have run into a brick wall. Can you see where I go wrong and suggest a solution?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: utf-8
"""MRE; needs installation of sine.threads ReStartableThread: pip3 install sine.threads"""
import sys
import time
import threading
from sine.threads import ReStartableThread as Thread


class MyThread(Thread):
    """
    drop-in replacement of ReStartableThread with status method added
    """

    def __init__(self, name=None, event_name=None, target=None, group=None, args=(), kwargs=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.event_name = event_name
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        super().__init__(name=name, event_name=event_name, target=target, group=group, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

    def status(self, i):  # placeholder
        print('dummy status #', i)


def threader(f):
    """ a threading decorator; put @threaded above the callable that needs threading """
    def threading_function(*args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread(name=f.__name__, target=f, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()

    return threading_function


@threader
def t0():
    time.sleep(3)
    t1.stop()
    t1.join()


class MyTimer:

    def __init__(self, name, kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():  # unpack kwargs and convert to variables
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __call__(self, stop_event):
        i = 5
        while not stop_event.is_set() and i > 0:
            print('I: ', i)
            time.sleep(1)
            i -= 1
        if stop_event.is_set():
            print('timer is CANCELLED')
        else:
            print('timer is FINISHED')


def main():
    global t1
    name = 'timer'
    t1_kwargs = {'interval': 99, 'message': 'STARTING COUNTDOWN...'}
    t1 = MyThread(name=name, target=MyTimer(name, t1_kwargs))
    t1.status(1)
    # first countdown
    t1.start()
    """
    The next statement fails with "AttributeError: 'StoppableThread' object has no attribute 'interval'"
    where StoppableThread is a member of the sine.threads module.
    Requirement: access to attributes (like interval) of instances of MyTimer from main
    """
    # print(t1.interval)
    t0()
    t1.join()
    t1.status(2)
    # second countdown
    t1.start()
    t1.status(3)
    t1.join()
    t1.status(4)
    print('END')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\b\b\r')
        print("PROGRAM TERMINATED AT USER'S REQUEST")
        force_exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are trying to initialize your base class `Thread` twice, first with

```
Thread.__init__(self)
```

and then with:

```
super().__init__(name=name, event_name=event_name, target=target, group=group, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
```

You should get rid of the first initialization.

Your problem is that you are assigning `t1` to your `MyThread` instance:

```
t1 = MyThread(name=name, target=MyTimer(name, t1_kwargs))
```

But `interval` is an attribute of your `MyTimer` instance, not your `MyThread` instance. So `t1.interval` will fail. You want:

```
t1 = MyTimer(name, t1_kwargs)
my_thread = MyThread(name, target=t1)
my_thread.status(1)
my_thread.start()
etc.
```

You just need to keep straight your two different instances:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: utf-8
"""MRE; needs installation of sine.threads ReStartableThread: pip3 install sine.threads"""
import sys
import time
import threading
from sine.threads import ReStartableThread as Thread


class MyThread(Thread):
    """
    drop-in replacement of ReStartableThread with status method added
    """

    def __init__(self, name=None, event_name=None, target=None, group=None, args=(), kwargs=None):
        self.name = name
        self.event_name = event_name
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        super().__init__(name=name, event_name=event_name, target=target, group=group, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

    def status(self, i):  # placeholder
        print('dummy status #', i)


def threader(f):
    """ a threading decorator; put @threaded above the callable that needs threading """
    def threading_function(*args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread(name=f.__name__, target=f, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()

    return threading_function


@threader
def t0():
    time.sleep(3)
    my_thread.stop()
    my_thread.join()


class MyTimer:

    def __init__(self, name, kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():  # unpack kwargs and convert to variables
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __call__(self, stop_event):
        i = 5
        while not stop_event.is_set() and i > 0:
            print('I: ', i)
            time.sleep(1)
            i -= 1
        if stop_event.is_set():
            print('timer is CANCELLED')
        else:
            print('timer is FINISHED')


def main():
    global t1
    global my_thread
    name = 'timer'
    t1_kwargs = {'interval': 99, 'message': 'STARTING COUNTDOWN...'}
    t1 = MyTimer(name, t1_kwargs)
    my_thread = MyThread(name, target=t1)
    my_thread.status(1)
    my_thread.start()
    print(t1.interval)
    t0()
    my_thread.join()
    my_thread.status(2)
    # second countdown
    my_thread.start()
    my_thread.status(3)
    my_thread.join()
    my_thread.status(4)
    print('END')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\b\b\r')
        print("PROGRAM TERMINATED AT USER'S REQUEST")
        force_exit()
```

Prints:

```
dummy status # 1
I:  5
99
I:  4
I:  3
timer is CANCELLED
dummy status # 2
I:  5
dummy status # 3
I:  4
I:  3
I:  2
I:  1
timer is FINISHED
dummy status # 4
END
```

Comment: Many thanks for the clear explanation and also for testing the code. My original programming training is in Algol68 and Pascal in the early 1970's so as you can see, I'm having a hard time getting to terms with OO programming.